# New Front Brake Calipers and Pads out of Allignment with New Rotors after Bearing Repack and Hub-Rebuild

Tags: toyota, wheels, brake-rotor, brake-calipers

i Just bought this 1993 Toyota 4x4 and am restoring it. i put on the new calipers and pads; and the inner pad is rubbing on the rotor; with a gap on the outer pad as you can see in the pictue.

there was alot of front end damage including broken cv joint on that side; previous owner lived on a reallly rough mountain road.. original calipers were siezed in the lower left piston and felt similar to the new calipers; i can turn the passenger tire axle but it has no momentum and stops right away because the inner pad is rubbing. with no caliper on it turns freely. on the drivers side it is alligned properly and spins with a bit of momentum on a hand turn.

i noticed this happening after passenger side bearing repack and hub rebuild.

[image: inner pad is tight and outer is loose with a bigger gap in the bottom right] [inner pad is tight and outer is loose with a bigger gap in the bottom right]

[[image: showing rotor allignment with backing plate... it is not rubbing the plate]showing rotor allignment with backing plate... it is not rubbing the plate

[image: this bolt is the only visible damage i can see.]this bolt is the only visible damage i can see.

[[image: i also had to replace the CV Rod that was completely broken at the joint where it enters the back of the wheel axle][i also had to replace the CV axle that was completely broken at the joint where it enters the back of the wheel axle]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you applied the brakes yet? ie stepped hard on the pedal to see if the caliper/pads center themselves? Does the caliper slide on its pins properly?

Comment: I'd say one of the caliper mount tabs on the spindle is bent slightly causing the binding. can you measure the tabs to the rotor?

Comment: Also, with the caliper off, it spins freely, but does it spin true or is there wobble? If it’s wobbling then you know the issue is rotor/hub alignment. If it spins true, then I’d lean toward caliper misalignment (possibly from bending damage).

Comment: and to elaborate on @kyle_engineer's comment - an amount of wobble might be very hard to see by eye, but still be enough to cause problems...

Comment: @NickC Yes! If you have something good and straight you can align next to it, that can help make the wobble more visible... the hard part is just being sure that straight too. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice.
With your clues i was able to do the tests and figure out the problem and fixed it.

Answers to comments questions:
Solar Mike:   yes i had applied the brakes already and it did not make a difference.

kyle_engineer: yes i looked very close for a wobble and there was a tiny wobble present.   so i went into all the local parts stores that i have been buying parts from;  with that information the mechanics were able to consult and advise me that the problem must be a bent " steering knuckle "  that is the part that both the brake calipers and the rotor mount onto.  it only happens from extreme heavy impacts/accidents and is not a common part to replace.  new it was $600-$700; but i was able to find one at the local scrap yard for $75.

Ben:  on my toyota the spindle and caliper mount is the same unit that is the " steering knuckle "  i could tell there was a problem by spinning the rotor and seeing if there was a wobble; so i didnt need to measure the distance from the caliper mount tabs to identify the problem; and it was difficult to do so as i dont have proper measuring calipers so i could not make a accurate measurement anyway.

I had it fixed within a few days of getting the clues here; could not have figured that one out without your help. Thank you very much i appreciate it alot. I could not comment or post earlier because i made the question in a guest account and had to wait for them to merge the question into the  account.

After installing the new steering knuckle; the rotor is no longer dragging on the pads;  and the calipers and rotors look like they are aligned as good as the drivers side. They both spin freely with alot of momentum now when i test spin the tires by hand with it jacked up.

however they are not really perfectly centered on either side; and i will be investigating if it is possible to make them exactly perfectly centered.  is that possible or is this as good as it gets?

here is some pics:

[image: new steering knuckle ready to be installed]

[image]

[image]

[image]